# qgis2web open file

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers, qgis2web

I am using the qgis2web plugin and everything works fine. I created few point objects in a shapefile layer on the map in QGIS.

What I want now is to add the possibility to open a (Excel) file when I click on the points on the map and which (Excel) file depends on which objects(points) in the map I click. But I cannot figure it out how to do that, both in OpenLayers as in Leaflet.

My question is: is it possible to let a Leaflet/OpenLayers file open a (Excel) file when I click on an object on the map and if so which is easier to learn: Leaflet/or OpenLayers? I don't know both so I'm not attached to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field in your layer which contains an address for the file. In other words, concatenate the path to the folder with whichever field gives each record its unique filename. qgis2web tries to detect links in popups, and makes them clickable.